# Unable to import Swift package that contains only Objc Code

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, swift-package-manager

I am trying to import a local swift package that only contains objective C files into an app using `@import MyLibrary;`. But it throws an error saying `Module 'MyLibrary' not found`.
Am I missing something in the package manifest or isn't this an allowed setup?

Package.swift

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyLibrary",
    platforms: [
            .iOS(.v12)
            ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyLibrary",
            targets: ["MyLibrary"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyLibrary"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyLibraryTests",
            dependencies: ["MyLibrary"]),
    ],
)
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like packed wasn't build

Comment: I found the issue, please check the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweaking the package.swift file fixed it

```
.target(
        name: "MyLibrary",
        dependencies: [],
        publicHeadersPath: "Public")
```

add a folder called `Public` inside the source folder and move all the public headers there. Now the package is visible in the project